# how can I retrieve the hashed password from mySql database with php?

Tags: php, mysql

My question supposed to be simple! although, I couldn't find the correct answer!

I need to retrieve the "hashed password" for the giving "username" from mySql database with php, then I need to store it in a variable, how could I do that?

All what I get is `"Resource id #5"`!

This is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT hashed_password ";
$query .= "FROM users ";
$query .= "WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
$query .= "AND hashed_password = '{$hashed_password}' ";
$query .= "LIMIT 1";
$result_set = mysql_query($query);
echo "$result_set"; 
echo '</br>';
```

Comment: `$query = "SELECT hashed_password ";
$query .= "FROM users ";
$query .= "WHERE username = '{$username}' "; $query .= "LIMIT 1";`

Comment: And what happens when you run the code you've already got? Do you get an error? Does it give the information?

Comment: But it's well past time for using the MySQL extension: it's nearly 2016 now, and you should be switching to MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements and bind variables

Comment: Sorry , but I just restart my php coding since 2 years!

Comment: @GeoffAtkins I got "Resource id #5"

Comment: Don't reply as a comment, edit your question so you are providing those who see it with all the information they might need to answer, and so that anyone else experiencing the same problem will be able to identify with it.

Answer (score 1):

To start off, let's use a MySQL library that supports prepared statements - otherwise, we'll run into SQL Injection issues in the future. Now, back to the actual question / answer.

If we use MySQLi, we have a few functions that will help us. Here's an example of an answer to your question w/ code comments to help walk through it:

```
// create our db connection
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'db_username', 'db_password', 'db_table');

// create a Prepared Statement to query to db
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT hashed_password FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1');

// dynamically bind the supplied "username" value
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

// execute the query
$stmt->execute();

// get the first result and store the first column in the `$hashed_password` variable
$stmt->bind_result($hashed_password);
$stmt->fetch();

// close our Prepared Statement and the db connection
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();

echo $hashed_password;
```

Check out the PHP Doc for [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for more examples =]

Note: I *highly* recommend avoiding the `mysql_query()` (and family) functions. They are not only deprecated, but they are quite insecure to use.

Comment: The original mysql-library fully supports data sanitation. In this case where he only uses one parameter, `mysqli_escape_string()` is absolutely enough.

Comment: I got error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$stmt'`

Comment: @MRAN sorry, there was a missing semicolon on the second line; added it =]

Comment: @BlackCetha "fully supports" is a bad statement. It provides users with a single method of sanitization, [`mysql_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_escape_string) and _that_ can only sanitize strings. If you're using a value that's not encapsulated in quotes, that function will protect you _absolutely none_. No, the proper course here is to demonstrate the use of a Prepared Statement, something the original library **does not have**. The MySQLi library _does_ have a similar method, [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](mysqli_real_escape_string), however, same issue arises =]

Comment: @newfurniturey thank you, I got another issue! `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean`

Comment: @MRAN That means you have an error in your SQL query. You may be able to get the exact error with `if (!$stmt) { echo $stmt->error; }`, but you know your schema the best so hopefully you can tell what / where the query error is

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the data out of the mysql-resource that is returned by a query.

Just pass it through `mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set)`. It will return your data in a nice and ordered arraay, moving ahead one row every call.
Meaning you can do
`while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set)`.

Also, please use mysqli. Its basically the same just with `mysqli` instead of `mysql` in commands. See the docs here for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php